# SQL Select en funcion del valor de un atributo no funciona como querría

Tags: sql, xampp

Contexto:
Es una practica de la universidad sobre hacer una base de datos sobre restaurantes, que son de una ciudad (las ciudades son de una zona), tienen un tipo de cocina (tipusCuina) en concreto, y tienen ofertas (menu o plato del día).

Tengo un problema con la siguiente consulta:
Necesito que haga select de los que NO tienen paella como primer plato y los que de por si no tienen menu, también.
El problema esta en que solo me da los que SI tienen menu que NO tienen paella de primer plato; no me da aquellos que directamente ni tienen menú (los menus son  ofertas).

```
SELECT 
restaurantciutattipuscuina.nomRestaurant, restaurantciutattipuscuina.tel, 
restaurantciutattipuscuina.domicili , restaurantciutattipuscuina.nombreForquilles,
zonaciutat.nomCiutat
FROM restaurantciutattipuscuina
INNER JOIN (restaurantoferta INNER JOIN primersegonpostremenu 
ON restaurantoferta.idOferta=primersegonpostremenu.idMenu)
ON restaurantciutattipuscuina.idRestaurant=restaurantoferta.idRestaurant 
INNER JOIN zonaciutat ON restaurantciutattipuscuina.idCiutat=zonaciutat.idCiutat
WHERE primersegonpostremenu.nomPrimerPlat!='paella'
```

Si hace falta que edite la pregunta y ponga más datos comentadmelo.
Qué problema veis en la consula? Por qué no me da los que no tienen una oferta (menu)?

EDIT: Incluyo los creates e inserts de datos.

- Creates:

```
CREATE DATABASE restaurants

CREATE TABLE Zona (
    nomZona        CHAR(30)    NOT NULL,
    idZona        CHAR(9)        PRIMARY KEY,
    descripcio    CHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE ZonaCiutat (
    idZona        CHAR(9)        NOT NULL,
    idCiutat    CHAR(9)        PRIMARY KEY,
    nomCiutat    CHAR(30)    NOT NULL,
    pais        CHAR(15),
    FOREIGN KEY (idZona)
   REFERENCES zona(idZona)
);


CREATE TABLE TipusCuina (
    supertipus  CHAR(30),
    descripcioTipus        CHAR(100),
    nomTipus        CHAR(30)    PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE RestaurantCiutatTipusCuina (
    idRestaurant CHAR(9)    PRIMARY KEY,
    idCiutat    CHAR(9)        NOT NULL,
    nomTipus    CHAR(30)    NOT NULL,
    nomRestaurant CHAR(30)    NOT NULL,
    tel            INT(30),
    domicili    CHAR(30),
    nombreForquilles INT(2),
    FOREIGN KEY (nomTipus)
    REFERENCES tipuscuina(nomTipus)
);

CREATE TABLE RestaurantOferta (
    idOferta    CHAR(9)        PRIMARY KEY,
    idRestaurant CHAR(9)    NOT NULL,
    dataOferta     DATE         NOT NULL,
    preu        DOUBLE        NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (idRestaurant)
    REFERENCES restaurantciutattipuscuina (idRestaurant)
);

CREATE TABLE Plat (
    nomPlat        CHAR(30)    PRIMARY KEY,
    vega        CHAR(2),
    foto        INT
);

CREATE TABLE PrimerSegonPostreMenu (
    idMenu        CHAR(9)         PRIMARY KEY,
    nomMenu    CHAR(30)    NOT NULL,
    nomPrimerPlat      CHAR(30),
    nomSegonPlat      CHAR(30),
    nomPostres     CHAR(30),
    FOREIGN KEY (idMenu)
    REFERENCES restaurantoferta(idOferta),
    FOREIGN KEY (nomPrimerPlat)
    REFERENCES plat(nomPlat),
    FOREIGN KEY (nomSegonPlat)
    REFERENCES plat(nomPlat),
    FOREIGN KEY (nomPostres)
    REFERENCES plat(nomPlat)
);

CREATE TABLE PlatDia (
    idOferta    CHAR(9)      PRIMARY KEY,
    nomPlat      CHAR(30)    NOT NULL,
    numpersones      INT(2),
  FOREIGN KEY (idOferta)
  REFERENCES restaurantoferta(idOferta),
 FOREIGN KEY (nomPlat)
  REFERENCES plat(nomPlat)
);

CREATE TABLE OfertaValoracio (
    idOferta    CHAR(9)      NOT NULL,
    idValoracio CHAR(9)      PRIMARY KEY,
    dataValoracio DATE,
    puntuacio    INT(1),
  FOREIGN KEY (idOferta)
  REFERENCES restaurantoferta(idOferta)
);
```

- Inserts:

```
INSERT INTO zona VALUES
('Llevant','123456789','est'),
('Tramuntana','987654321','nord'),
('Palma','678912345','oest'),
('Raiguer','543219876','centre-nord')

INSERT INTO TipusCuina VALUES 
('Asiatica', 'Descripcio cuina Japonesa', 'Japonesa'),
('Asiatica', 'Descripcio cuina Xinesa', 'Xinesa'),
('Asiatica', 'Descripcio cuina Coreana', 'Coreana'),
('Asiatica', 'Descripcio cuina Afgana', 'Afgana'),
('Europea', 'Descripcio cuina Mallorquina', 'Mallorquina')


INSERT INTO zonaciutat VALUES
('543219876','500000000','Binissalem','Espanya'),
('123456789','100000000','Manacor','Espanya'),
('123456789','100000001','Arta','Espanya'),
('987654321','900000000','Valldemossa','Espanya'),
('678912345','600000000','PalmadeMallorca','Espanya')

INSERT INTO Plat VALUES 
('arròs brut', 'no', '54848'),
('crema de brocoli', 'si', '39475'),
('bistec a la plancha', 'no', '23438'),
('porcella', 'no', '56387'),
('hamburguesa', 'si', '98875'), 
('pijama','no','64764'),
('paella','si','99884'),
('arros xines','no','28739'),
('chop suey pollo','no','87204'),
('ramen','si','89345'),
('kabuli pulao','no','39789'),
('gogi gui','no','36986'),
('gelat','no','67987')


INSERT INTO restaurantciutattipuscuina VALUES
('010000000','500000000','Japonesa','Daruma','971000000','Carrer Gris','2'), ('010000001','500000000','Xinesa','Wawa','971000001','Carrer Negre','4'), ('010000002','100000000','Afgana','Fera','971000002','Carrer Vermell','3'), ('010000003','100000001','Mallorquina','Ca’n Joan','971000003','Carrer Groc','2'),
('010000004','600000000','Coreana','Bi Bap','971000004','Carrer Verd','5'), ('010000005','900000000','Mallorquina','Ca’n Pedro','971000005','Carrer Blau','5');

INSERT INTO restaurantoferta VALUES 
 ('1', '010000001', DATE('2008-05-17 11:31:31'), 15.99),
 ('2', '010000000', DATE('2009-05-17 12:32:31'), 13.99),
 ('3', '010000003', DATE('2009-08-07 12:02:30'), 9.99),
 ('4', '010000005', DATE('2013-12-17 10:02:31'), 21.99),
 ('5', '010000004', DATE('2017-06-22 11:08:32'), 18.99);

INSERT INTO ofertavaloracio VALUES
 ('1','000000000','2018-02-27','5'), 
 ('1','000000001','2018-05-12','4'),
 ('2','000000002','2019-01-05','2'),
 ('3','000000003','2018-10-28','3'),
 ('3','000000004','2018-11-23','2'),
 ('4','000000005','2018-06-18','5'),
 ('5','000000006','2018-03-10','1');

INSERT INTO primersegonpostremenu VALUES
('1','menuxines','arros xines', 'chop suey pollo', 'gelat'),
('2','menujapones','ramen','bistec a la plancha','gelat'),
('3','menucanjoan','paella','hamburguesa','gelat'),
('4','menucanpedro', 'arròs brut', 'porcella','pijama'),
('5','menucoreano','ramen','gogi gui', 'gelat');


INSERT INTO platdia (idOferta, nomPlat, numpersones) VALUES
 (1, 'ramen', 1),
 (2, 'chop suey pollo', 1),
 (3, 'arròs brut', 2),
 (4, 'paella', 7);
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si das más datos, (estructura y relaciones entre tablas, y demás), podremos ayudarte más, por ahora a ver si puede valerte esto. No lo he probado, pero algo así debería ser lo que buscas. He intentado hacer las mínimas modificaciones a tu código (solo he cambiado un INNER JOIN por un LEFT JOIN). Por lo que entiendo de la estructura, debería sacar lo que quieres:

```
SELECT 
restaurantciutattipuscuina.nomRestaurant, restaurantciutattipuscuina.tel, 
restaurantciutattipuscuina.domicili , restaurantciutattipuscuina.nombreForquilles,
zonaciutat.nomCiutat
FROM restaurantciutattipuscuina
LEFT JOIN (restaurantoferta INNER JOIN primersegonpostremenu 
ON restaurantoferta.idOferta=primersegonpostremenu.idMenu)
ON restaurantciutattipuscuina.idRestaurant=restaurantoferta.idRestaurant 
INNER JOIN zonaciutat ON restaurantciutattipuscuina.idCiutat=zonaciutat.idCiutat
WHERE primersegonpostremenu.nomPrimerPlat!='paella'
```

EDICIÓN: Veo que la estructura es distinta a lo que pensaba, he recolocado el LEFT JOIN, a ver si ahora funciona. De todas formas, por sencillez, sería más sencillo usar un UNION ALL, y recoger primero unos y luego otros.

EDICIÓN2: La condición del WHERE solo se aplica cuando existe una entrada en la tabla restaurantoferta que puede hacer INNER JOIN con primersegonpostremenu. Prueba a añadir "OR restaurantoferta.idOferta IS NULL".

Comment: Ahora he añadido los creates y los inserts a ver si aclara más la situación. Probé el select que me has puesto per sigue dandome solo los cuatro restaurantes que NO tienen paella en el primer plato. Eso está bien, pero me falta que me de un restaurante más que directamente ni tiene menú.

Comment: Si, igualmente sigue dandome solo los que tienen el primer plato diferente de 'paella'. Me he fijado que quitando la condición del where, me saca todos los restaurantes, así que los joins están bien. Es la condicion del where la que me excluye al restaurante que tiene NULL en el primer plato (que deberia mostrarlo el select). Probé usando una OR con la condicion primerPlat = NULL, pero nada. No se me ocurre qué más probar.

Comment: Vale, ahora lo entendí con la aclaración del INNER JOIN. Puse el OR que dices y ha funcionado. ¡Muchas gracias!